# Check and validate that a string does not contain 4 separate characters

Tags: vba

I have some VBA code that performs some transformations on an output string which is built earlier in the process. The transform adds an ID surrounded by square brackets, and another identifier surrounded by curly brackets. The ID number and identifier can both be any length and contain any combination of alphanumeric characters. As part of the process I might need to process an Output string which has already been processed and has the ID number and identifier already included.

I can only perform the transform if I get a valid ResultCode, so I need to make sure that ResultCode is above 7 characters in length before running the transform.

I also want to check the string before I perform the transform on it, and if it already has both the square brackets and the curly brackets, I want to skip the transform and avoid adding them again. If it only has one or the other, I want to go ahead and do the transform.

My current logic looks like this:

```
            If Len(ResultCode) > 7 _
            And InStr(strOutput, "[") = 0 _
            And InStr(strOutput, "]") = 0 _
            And InStr(strOutput, "{") = 0 _
            And InStr(strOutput, "}") = 0 Then                                                                             
                'Do the transform
            End If
```

However, this is finding false-positives. e.g. If the string already contains only one curly bracket it is not doing the transform.

How can I check that the ResultCode is 8 characters or longer, and strOutput does not contain all four bracket characters?

Comment: Just to clarify, that the string will be "_valid_" if it is at least 8 characters long and contains up to any three of these characters `[]{}`, but not all four?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the checks for the string from `And` to `Or`

```
 If Len(ResultCode) > 7 _
    And ( InStr(strOutput, "[") = 0 _
       Or InStr(strOutput, "]") = 0 _
       Or InStr(strOutput, "{") = 0 _
       Or InStr(strOutput, "}") = 0 ) Then
```

In that case, the transform will be executed whenever at least one of the special characters is missing.

However, if I where you, I would move that check into a function:

```
Function isProcessed(code As String) As Boolean
    isProcessed = (InStr(code, "[") > 0 _
                And InStr(code, "]") > 0 _
                And InStr(code, "{") > 0 _
                And InStr(code, "}") > 0)
End Function
```

and in your routine you simply write

```
If Len(ResultCode) > 7  And Not isProcessed(strOutput) Then
```

You can easily test this function (eg using the immediate window) without the need to execute all the code. And you can easily improve the logic (for example check if the square brackets and curly brackets are also in specific order).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to express either `[` and `]`, or `{` and `}`, but not both:

```
If Len(ResultCode) > 7 _
And ( _
    InStr(strOutput, "[") > 0 And InStr(strOutput, "]") > 0 _
    And InStr(strOutput, "{") = 0 And InStr(strOutput, "}") = 0 _
) Or ( _
    InStr(strOutput, "[") = 0 And InStr(strOutput, "]") = 0 _
    And InStr(strOutput, "{") > 0 And InStr(strOutput, "}") > 0 _
) Then                                                                             
    'Do the transform
End If
```